# javascript выбрать ВСЕ теги на странице

Tags: javascript, теги

написал скрипт для Tampermonkey который при наведении на элемент подсвечивает его и показывает его tagName, id, classList (как в дебаггере браузеров)

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var css = '.hglightblock { background-color:#ccf !important; }',
        head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    style = document.createElement('style'),
    popuptooltip=document.createElement('div');
    popuptooltip.id="popuptooltip";
    popuptooltip.style.position="absolute";
    head.appendChild(style);
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(popuptooltip);
    style.type = 'text/css';
    if (style.styleSheet){
       // This is required for IE8 and below.
      style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
    } else {
      style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
    }


    //var list=Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("*"));
    //document.getElementsByTagName("*")

    document.querySelectorAll("body *")
    .forEach(function(c){
        let tag=c.tagName;
        let cid=c.getAttribute("id")!=null?c.getAttribute("id"):"";
        let cl=c.className!=null&&c.className.length>0?c.className:"";

        c.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e){
            document.querySelector("#popuptooltip").innerHTML=tag+(cid!=""?"<b style='color:blue'>#"+cid+"</b>":"")+(cl!=""?"<b style='color:green'>."+cl+"</b>":"");
            document.querySelector("#popuptooltip").setAttribute("style", "padding:5px;position:absolute;top:"+(e.pageY+15)+"px;left:"+(e.pageX+15)+"px;border:1px solid black;background-color:white;");
            e.stopPropagation();
        })
        c.addEventListener("mouseover",function(e){
            c.classList.add("hglightblock")
            e.stopPropagation();
        })
        c.addEventListener("mouseout",function(e){
            c.classList.remove("hglightblock")
            e.stopPropagation();
        })
    })
})();
```

на многих сайтах работает нормально. но например на Stackoverflow не совсем: в блоке с кодом есть теги span.

```
<code class="">
<span class="pln"></span>
<span class="kwd">import</span><span class="pln"> android</span><span class="pun">.</span><span class="pln">app</span><span class="pun">.</span><span class="typ">Notification</span><span class="pun">;</span><span class="pln">
</code>
```

теги span внутри code не определяются скриптом.
для выборки всех тегов на странице использовал варианты:

```
var list=document.querySelectorAll("body *")
var list=Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("*"));
var list=document.getElementsByTagName("*");
```

результат одинаковый

**UPD:**

поменял `(function(){ })()` на `window.onload=function(){...}` - все работает

Comment: то есть, не работает только на тегах `span`, которые внутри тегов `code`?

Comment: @Август да. возможно и на других сайтах будет такое же поведение, то что под рукой было на том и потестил

Comment: у меня Ваш скрипт работает (на `span` внутри `code` включительно). кстати, интересная вещь, буду пользоваться им, если Вы не против

Comment: @Август да пожалуйста. у вас какой браузер?

Comment: гуглХром. но это, видимо, не важно, так как на FF тоже работает, только что проверил

Comment: попробуйте просто свой скрипт вставить в консоль браузера, когда страница прогрузится. если и у Вас заработает, значит будет отталкиваться от этого дальше

Comment: @Август нашел причину. добавил в вопрос

Comment: чёрт) Вы меня опередили) я как раз дал Вам ответ

Comment: @Август ну ладно, зачту )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

а теперь, отталкиваясь от дискуссии в комментариях, можно сделать вывод, что Ваш скрипт не работает в из-за того, что первоначально содержимое в тегах `<code>` на страницах этого сайта (*StackOverflow*) приходит как строка (это можно посмотреть через вкладку `Network` => `Doc` => `входящий html файл`), то есть внутри `<code>` еще нет сформированных `<span>` тегов. они создаются потом `js` скриптом.

решение проблемы:

```
document.addEventListener('load', вашаФункцияСКодом);
```